# How to import a data from sql server to excel?

Tags: sql-server

I want to get a date from sql server into excel

How can i do it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Data - >
import External data -> 
import data -> 
select NewSource -> 
what kind of data source do you want to connect to?(select Microsoft SQL Server) -> 
next (authentication server) -> 
next ->  
select the database that contains the data you want? (select  your database) -> 
select the table and click Finish
```

Answer (score 0):

export it into csv format and then open it through excel...short and nice